# Passing props to header component

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

In my react native mobile app I have a login functionality and register functionality. User is logged in using email and password using firebase authentication. After logged in I need to be able to show user's name in the header component. But in my app I am using stack navigator, drawer navigator and bottom tab navigator. So, for navigation I have created separate js file called **Router**.

```
const ThirdNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    LoginForm,
    RegisterForm
});

const SecondNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Profile: {
      screen: TaskList,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Your Schedule'
      })
    }
}, {
    // drawerType: 'slide', 
});

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Open: { screen: OpenWindow },
    Home: {
        screen: ThirdNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: 'Sign In',
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#0680EC', height: 45 },
            headerLeft: null,
            headerRight: null
        })
    },
    Profile: {
        screen: SecondNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'Your Schedule',
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#0680EC', height: 45 },
          headerLeft: <Toggle navigation={navigation} />,
          headerRight: <Notification logOutUser={logOutUser()} />
        })
    }
});


const Router = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default connect(null, { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser, logOutUser })(Router);
```

As I got to know, when I am using react-redux connect function, I can't use navigation options in main UI component. So, I had to use navigation options in **Router**. My header is a separate component called **Notification.js**.

```
class Notification extends Component {
  state = {
      user_name: 'label',
      loading: true,
      level: ''
  };


  onSelectOpt(idx, value) {
      this.setState({ level: value });
      if (value === "Logout") {
        firebase.auth().signOut();
      }
  }

  showLogout() {
      return (
          <ModalDropdown options={[this.state.user_name, 'Logout']} onSelect={(idx, value) => this.onSelectOpt(idx, value)} style={{ width: '100%', height: 30, justifyContent: 'center', paddingLeft: 20 }} dropdownStyle={{ width: 100, height: 82, paddingBottom: 0 }} dropdownTextStyle={{ color: '#000', fontSize: 15 }} dropdownTextHighlightStyle={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} >
            <View style={{ height: 30, width: 60, alignItems: 'center', paddingRight: 20 }}>
                <Image
                    source={require('../pics/logout.png')}
                    style={styles.downStyle}
                />
            </View>
        </ModalDropdown>
      );
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingRight: 10 }}>
              <View style={{ height: 30, width: 60, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
                  {this.showLogout()}
              </View>
          </View>
      )
   }
}


const styles = {
    imageStyle: {
        width: 25,
        height: 25
    },
    buttonStyle: {
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 7
    },
    spinnerStyle: {
       alignSelf: 'stretch',
       borderRadius: 5,
       marginLeft: 20,
       marginRight: 20,
       borderRadius: 60,
       paddingTop: 10,
       paddingBottom: 10,
       height: 100
    },
    downStyle: {
        width: 25,
        height: 25
    }
}

export { Notification };
```

My problem is, after I fetched user's name from firebase database, how can I pass it as a prop to my header. I call my action creator in main UI component after logged in. But navigation options are in **Router**. So, I'm looking for a way to pass fetched data as a prop to Header(**Notification.js**).

```
class TaskList extends Component {

  handleBackButtonClick() {
  BackHandler.exitApp();
  return true;
}

UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
  this.props.userFetch();
  // console.log(this.props.username.name);
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this));
}

UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // console.log(nextProps.username);
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser == null) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  }
}

render() {
  console.log(this.props);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Employee</Text>
      <Text>Employee</Text>
      <Text>Employee</Text>
      <Text>Employee</Text>
      <Text>Employee</Text>
      <Text>Employee</Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const username = _.map(state.username, (val, uid) => {
    return { ...val, uid };
  });

  return { username };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { userFetch })(TaskList);
```

I have successfully fetched data from firebase and converted it into a array in main UI. Now I want a way to pass that data to the header **Notification.js** component. Please help me to figure out a way to do this.